# ProcessStartInfo from Service doesn't work when user isn't logged in

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a windows service, written in C#, using Topshelf.

I want to kick off a Powershell script, which needs to run as Administrator.

```
var workingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(psScriptPath) ?? Environment.CurrentDirectory;

var process = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe",
        Arguments = string.Format("-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File \"{0}\"", psScriptPath),
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
        WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory,
        Verb = runAsAdmin ? "runas" : null,
        UseShellExecute = true,
        CreateNoWindow = false
    }
};

process.Start();
```

The service is running as an Administrator account.

Now, here is the strange thing. When the service is running on a brand new machine and I trigger the code above nothing happens. No except is thrown and the script does not appear to be run (it uses the Powershell Transcript command, and no log file is created).

However - if I am logged into the machine, and the same code is triggered then the code runs successfully.

I've tried everything I can think of - file permissions, LoadUserProfile = true, disabling UAC (even in the registry) and nothing seems to work. I can't think of any other way of finding out what is happening as I can't be logged in on the machine.

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Services cannot create interactive Windows unless a specific permission in the security policy is set.

This is also a potential security risk as services are by design not meant to be interactive.

Are you sure you need to have the PS script run in an interactive window?

Comment: In order to do the "runas" Verb (for running as admin) you need to use shell execute - if you use shell execute you can't do a hidden window.

Comment: That's why I am asking about alternative solutions. Also you should be able to configure a service user as an Administrator privilege level account. Bear in mind "run as" on certain configurations requires entering of credentials which for an unattended service will break your desired behaviour.

Comment: The service is running as an administrator, but if the script isn't explicitly elevated then it fails (due to registry access requirements). It is the fact that it works when the user is logged in, without showing any UI or requiring consent confuses me.

Comment: Again, services cannot show interactive windows without changing a security policy. Your `ProcessStartInfo` has `CreateNoWindow = false` and `WindowStyle = Normal`. Windows may silently kill the request due to the security policy (these things happen).

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem of trying to start an application (if it was closed for ANY reason) from a service. Worked when running as a console app. But could not be done when running as a service.

I ended up making an entirely different application to do what I needed. I created a windows form application with a minimized window state and a tray icon. I then had it's installer project create a shortcut in the user's startup folder. I then had the application continually run a timer every second. To check if the application's process (in this case a UWP app) was running. If not, I start the process.

Followed this post to do it. Took like 20 minutes to get going and does what I needed and what I was trying to do from my service.